# Using grep with a pattern that contains a variable to be expanded

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I have a file on the form

```
2e95d7582c53583fa8afb54e0fe7a2597c92cbba 1461065389 52880 temp/hello/file.txt
46c897a7aa8a641f46080b3431860bd0cd4a8f05 1461066221 207 temp/Another file.txt
83c8ce6b163ec1c615617fa0dbde9e928bc3daf4 1461056193 86112 Pictures/a photo.jpg
...
```

That is, each line has a 40-character long hex number, followed by space, an integer, space, an integer, space, and a file path that may contain spaces. Each path is unique.

In a bash script I have variables on the same form as a line in the file, only without the first hex string and space (41 first characters), e.g.:

```
myvar="1461066221 207 temp/Another file.txt"
```

My goal is to find *the* line in the file that matches `myvar` *exactly* when the first 41 characters are ignored. If such a match is found I would like the variable `line` to be set to the full line in the file. For the example above, `line` would be set to

```
46c897a7aa8a641f46080b3431860bd0cd4a8f05 1461066221 207 temp/Another file.txt
```

If there is no such match, `line` should be set to the empty string, or left unset.

My solution is this (`filelist` is the name of file):

```
line=$(grep --color=never -E "^.{41}$myvar$" $filelist)
```

A problem is that when `$myvar` is expanded it might contain special symbols like `.`, `+`, even `^` or `$`, etc, which have a special meaning for `grep`. I want `grep` to perform an *exact* match of `myvar` on all but the first 41 characters of a line.

Comment: Can the variable only match the end of the string? If so, you could use `grep`'s `-F` option. You just can't specify "at the end" with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
export myvar
awk 'substr($0, 42) == ENVIRON["myvar"]' < "$filelist"
```

Comment: Given the concise, and for me very understandable, solution I choose this as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $search = shift }
          print if /^.{41}\Q$search\E$/;
         ' -- "$myvar" "$filelist"
```

- `-n` reads the file line by line.
- The BEGIN block retrieves the $myvar from the first argument into Perl variable $search.
- `\Q...\E` quotes the inner part (see [quotemeta](http://p3rl.org/quotemeta)). This handles all the special characters the variable can contain. Don't forget to double quote the shell variables!

Comment: Oh no, not Perl! ;) My whole life I've successfully avoided Perl. Anyway, cheers! I've tested your solution and it seems robust! I will adopt it into my script for now.

Comment: @DustByte: Your life might have been much easier ;-) Don't listen to haters, use the right tool for the job!

Answer (score 3):

This is a different way to go; it first sets 'line' to be empty, and sets it if it finds that 'myvar' matches the trailing 3 fields.

```
line=
while IFS=' ' read -r hex int1 int2 rest
do
  if [[ "$myvar" = "$int1 $int2 $rest" ]]
  then
    line="$hex $int1 $int2 $rest"
  fi
done < filelist
```

Here's yet another way, using bash's `mapfile` builtin and second temporary associative array:

```
mapfile -t < filelist # sets MAPFILE array
declare -A temparray
shopt -s extglob
for val in "${MAPFILE[@]}"
do 
  short="${val##*([^ ]) }"
  temparray[$short]="$val"
done
line=${m[$myvar]}
unset -v MAPFILE temparray val short
```

This brings the file in to an indexed array MAPFILE, which we then loop over. The loop sets the "short" variable to the "suffix" part of the line -- it strips out leading values that match the pattern "zero or more non-spaces followed by a space", then sets the associative array value for "$short" to be the whole line ("$val"). Doing this sort of matching with the `*` requires `shopt -s extglob` to be in effect. We then set line to be the resulting value (or if that value doesn't exist in the array, bash will return the empty/null value).

Comment: I like the idea of reading the file into an associative array. I can imagine this will speed up the look-ups. And yes, I do intend to do many of those! However, I tried your script on my file (around 80,000 lines) and after half an hour of all fans at high speed, I interrupted. The for-loop seems to take very long.